# Convert JSON array to VB.NET array

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, json, visual-studio-2010

I have a very simple JSON array and I would like to convert it to a VB.NET array. The JSON is:

```
{"UPTIME": "UNKNOWN", "VERSION ": 2.0, "SENDTIME": "03:33:52",  "SENDDATE": "28- 12-2012", "HOSTNAME": "My-PC"}
```

In this case `[0]="UNKNOWN"`, `[1]=2.0`, `[2]=03:33:52`, etc.

I've read through previous questions and I'm just getting more confused and they all seem to be for more complex examples of json than I have. I am using the Newtonsoft.Json library as that seems to be recommended a lot, but I don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working in the end with random experimentation this produces a dictionary with the values in, which is close enough so I can create the variables I wanted without having to use a VB.NET array I thought I would have to use I hope this helps others:

Imports:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

Declared variables:

```
Dim json As String 'this is the string of json data that needs decoding
Dim version As String
Dim obj As New JObject
```

Conversion code:

```
json = '{"UPTIME": "UNKNOWN", "VERSION ": 2.0, "SENDTIME": "03:33:52",  "SENDDATE": "28- 12-2012", "HOSTNAME": "My-PC"}'
Dim deserializedProduct As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(json)
obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(recv)
uptime = obj.Item("UPTIME").ToString
version = obj.Item("VERSION").ToString
Console.WriteLine(uptime)
Console.WriteLine(version)
```

Result:

```
UNKNOWN
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json.Net a .Net JSON Converter library.  From what I see you should be able to convert the string to a Json object, then you can write a cast method to build an array from the members of that JSON object.

http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used any of those so I'm not aware of the usefuleness of it. There's a Json serializer class built-in .net [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.aspx)